# Adding a column B with R in a .csv based on row strings of another column A

Tags: r

I have uploaded a .csv on R. It has different columns. One column includes four different colors (white, pink, blue, black) differently distributed in many rows. Other columns include for example an ID and the name of a city. Like this (there are more than three columns in my .csv file)

```
data =

COLOR    PAINTING ID    CITY
pink     284            London
white    1984           Madrid
blue     1939           London
black    19238          Rome
black    2992           New York
white    1123           Washington
black    1002           Moscow
pink     1499           Copenhagen 
blue     3984           Moscow
...
```

I'd like to subset the data, adding a column to my .csv distinguishing between light colors (white, pink) and dark colors (blue, black). In other words, I want to obtain this:

```
data =

COLOR    PAINTING ID    CITY         darkness
pink     284            London       light
white    1984           Madrid       light
blue     1939           London       dark
black    19238          Rome         dark
black    2992           New York     dark
white    1123           Washington   light
black    1002           Moscow       dark
pink     1499           Copenhagen   light
blue     3984           Moscow       dark
...
```

If I wanted to subset, say, 'black' only, I'd do

```
data$darkness = ifelse(data$COLOR == 'black', 'dark', 'light')
```

but I have to put both 'black' and 'blue' together, and a function `data$darkness` doesn't seem applicable. How can I do?

Comment: try ```data$COLOR %in% c('black','blue')``` instead of ```data$COLOR == 'black'```

Comment: Also, a minor term correction: **subset** generally means to reduce the number of rows or columns. Here, you're adding column and keeping the number of rows the same, so I would not say you're subsetting the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could have, for example another dataframe with pairs of color and darkness and then do an inner join by color. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(COLOR=c("blue", "black", "pink"), darkness=c("dark", "dark", "light"))

data <- data %>% inner_join(df, by = COLOR)
```

Note that inner_join function is from dplyr package